# MSBuild argument to let pickles import test results causes Illegal path error

Tags: tfs, msbuild, specflow, picklesdoc

We are using SpecFlow to apply BDD practices and Pickles to generate the documentation.

Our build looks like this:

1. Build
2. Deploy
3. Test (using VSTest)
4. Generate documentation (using Pickles)

The generate documentation step comes after the Test step, so we can include testresults to pickles. I want to use pickles as a build step, so I can manage the pickles version to use and additional options in each Solution.

The Visual Studio Build step in TFS2017 looks like this:

```
/t:DocumentationGeneration 
/p:Pickles_Generate=True 
/p:Pickles_DocumentationFormat=dhtml
/p:Pickles_ResultsFile="$(build.sourcesdirectory)/TestResults/*.trx"
/p:Pickles_OutputDirectory="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/PickledDocumentation"
    [some more generic parameters that are not relevant here]
```

When I do the above, I get an "Illegal character in path" error during the build. It seems to be the `*` causing this error, when I replace it with `/p:Pickles_ResultsFile="$(build.sourcesdirectory)/TestResults/testresults.trx"` there is no problem at all, only the testresults are not found because the testresults are in the non predictive format:
`USERNAME_SERVERNAME1234 2017-02-02 09_09_09.trx`

I tried to look into generating a generic name for the .trx file, but VSTest does not support custom names. Did anyone else encounter this problem and is there a nice approach to solve it?

Comment: There's probably no other option than to figure out the exact filename. That is not too hard, it's built-in msbuild functionality, principle would be to pass a custom 'PicklesResultsDir' to the project and withing the project have msbuild look for the files with `<Pickles_ResultsFile Include="$(PicklesResultsDir)\*.trx"/>`.  You don't say what your solution/project layout is though so I cannot tell you where exactly to put this logic.

Answer (score 2):

Pickles only supports the exact name of the test result file. There is an [issue](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles/issues/401) on the GitHub project site to allow wildcards. As the maintainer of Pickles, I will be happy to review any pull requests that address that issue.

Comment: Hi @dirk-rombauts, thanks for your great product. I will look into it and maybe I can even push a fix! (I have a real-life testcase anyways :).). Right now I solved it by renaming the .trx file with another build step.

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to make it work for you! Feel free to ask if there are any other Pickles-related things I might be able to help you with.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT done. Will update when appropriate (ie wildcards are supported).

Answer (score 0):

At request: This is how I solved it. It is more a work around that works in my particular situation, but at the bottom I explain how I hope it will be fixed soon.

1. Create a Command Line build step right after test build step
2. as tool use `Rename`
3. as arguments use `"$(build.sourcesdirectory)\TestResults\*.trx" TestResults.trx`

Now you can use a Visual Studio Build step to generate pickles documentation (you need to have pickles as NuGet package in your project)

1. As Solution set `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/yourproject.csproj`
2. As buildarguments set additional parameters:

   ```
   /t:DocumentationGeneration 
   /p:Pickles_Generate=True  
   /p:Pickles_DocumentationFormat=dhtml
   /p:Pickles_ResultsFile="$(build.sourcesdirectory)/TestResults/TestResults.trx" 
   /p:Pickles_ResultsFormat="vstest"
   /p:Pickles_OutputDirectory="yourdestinationpath"
   ```

As I said, the renaming is a bit a work around, so I extended the code of pickles itself to enable wildcard support, and is now [a pull request in the pickles repo](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles/pull/421), so hopefully it is implemented in the next release and you all can use it that way :).